# Firebase UI Auth widget in Angular application

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-authentication, firebaseui

I only want to include the FirebaseUI Auth widget on my login page (controlled via ngRoute).

However, the top-level JS throws this error on all other pages:

"Uncaught Error: Could not find the Firebase UI widget element on the page."

While the error is technically correct, it's annoying as that widget shouldn't be on all pages.

Has anyone thought of a neat way to suppress this?

Thanks,
Ned

Answer (score -3):

You need Firebase Auth to work across all pages that require authentication, therefore you will need to have the Firebase Web SDK/Javascript loaded for those pages.  As for the widget element not being there, is there not a set of elements required for the widget to work with?

If there are, add them.  If there is not, they should be loaded by the SDK automatically (like how it loads iFrames in the regular Web SDK).  The console is telling you the elements are missing.

I know you will get richer error handling/messages if you host the firebase scripts vs loading them via CDN.  You could try that.

If you want to hide the widget elements, it seems like CSS could `display:none` you might have to add the `!important` declaration.

Comment: Thanks. I am using Firebase Auth across all pages, and that's fine.  I'm talking about Firebase Auth UI (separate script).  That's the literal login box ("Click here to signin with Facebook", etc).  That only wants to be on one page.  I _could_ put it on all pages then hide on all but login page, but that's pretty lame.

Comment: Downvote because this literally does not address the question at all,  and in fact ignores the question itself.